# Mysql 5.5 Ruby DBI Segmentation

Tags: mysql, ruby, dbi

The Segfault appears to be on closing the connection

```
begin
  dbh = DBI.connect("DBI:Mysql:testdb:localhost", "user", "pass")

  rows = dbh.do("INSERT IGNORE INTO `HS_pList` (projName, projSource, projLink, projHash, projLoc) Values ('" + dbh.escape_string(@name) + "','" + @source + "','" + @link + "','" + @hash + "','" + @loc + "')")

rescue DBI::DatabaseError => e
  puts "Error code: #{e.err}"
  puts "Error message: #{e.errstr}"
ensure
  dbh.disconnect if dbh
end
```

I had a ; at the end of the string for the insert but it did not change anything. I get the same error if all i am doing is opening and closing an error does any one have an Idea of why. All the variables are set for constructing the string.

mysql 5.5
ruby 1.9.2p180
dbi 0.4.5
dbd-mysql 0.4.4
mysql 2.8.1 x86-mingw32

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out what it was I had to copy the libmysql.dll to the ruby bin and I also tried copying the libmysqld.dll and now it works must have the proper disconnects in that one?